# I just got First Responder (and it isn't New Years yet)

Tags: bug, winterbash-2016

I've just been awarded First Responder:

[image: "You earned First Responder on Role-playing Games!]

Despite the fact that shouldn't be possible for 2017 yet:

[image: "post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred"]

But I did have a message starred in chat around new years' during last Winterbash. Did the year not get set properly?

I haven't had a message posted by me starred in chat for a few days.

[wears his buggy hat nevertheless]

Comment: this has happened to me as well, just to illustrate that it isn't just one person

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that was a bug. Fixed now, thanks! The details are in [First Responder hat of the 2016 winter bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288273/first-responder-hat-of-the-2016-winter-bash).